# Suppress AWS CDK output to stdout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When I run `cdk deploy *` the process prints to console something like that:

> ✅  PrefixRandomMainStackPrefixRandomCmkStackB7461D3C
> (Prefix-Random-Cmk-Stack) (no changes)
>
> Outputs:
> PrefixRandomMainStackPrefixRandomCmkStackB7461D3C.ExportsOutputFnGetAttPrefixRandomCmk6E87F415ArnD999CC18
> = arn:aws:kms:some-region-2:12345678910:key/123-123-123-123-9aadccac4deb
>
> Stack ARN: PrefixRandomMainStackPrefixRandomRandomApiStackD1546C35
> (Prefix-Random-RandomApi-Stack)
> PrefixRandomMainStackPrefixRandomRandomApiStackD1546C35
> (Prefix-Random-RandomApi-Stack): deploying...
>
> ✅  PrefixRandomMainStackPrefixRandomRandomApiStackD1546C35
> (Prefix-Random-RandomApi-Stack) (no changes)

etc.

***Is there a way to suppress all this output?***

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a *nix like shell you could use

```
cdk deploy > /dev/null 2>&1
```